# A field goes off the page when using jspdf-html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm using 'jspdf-html2canvas' and a text field that contains lots of text, is leading off the right hand side of the page. I've tried too many things to list to try to get it to wrap on multiple lines but nothing has worked. Here's the current code:

```
<div id="page" >
           <div className="page page-1">
             <br /> 
             <table>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <th>EIA Ref</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>{this.state.PolicyOwnerTitle}</td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
           </div>
           <div className="page page-2" >
             <br /> 
             <table >
                 <tr  >
                   <td>{this.state.Beneficiaries}</td> //this is the one!
                 </tr>
             </table>
           </div>

public documentPrint2 = (e) => {
    const pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');

    html2PDF(pages, {
      jsPDF: {
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'a4',
        orientation: 'p',
        
      },
      html2canvas: {
        imageTimeout: 15000,
        logging: true,
        useCORS: false,
        windowWidth: '1000px',
        
      },
      margin: {
        margin: {
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
      },
    },
      imageType: 'image/jpeg',
      imageQuality: 1,
      output: this.state.PPName+'.pdf',
      
    });
  }
```

And here is what is happening:

[image]

Anyone know how I can wrap the field(s)?

UPDATE: I can put the text into a  in the html so the text will appear in as it's wrapping in a box, but when the pfg is generated, it still shows the text on one line.

FURTHER UPDATE: If I type in just text in the html (e.g. a long piece of text) it works fine. The problem is if I use `{this.state.Beneficiaries}`

What other option have I got??!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just change the column in SharePoint to plain text. Not sure why it does that with rich text or enhanced.